# Data storage from JavaScript

Tags: iphone

I need to store some values from JavaScript function and access those values from Objective C . Is that possible? Please give me a solution

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to dynamically update form values with the javascript and then post the form and grab the values with objective C.